# How do I set text wrapping property for a content of a button in Windows universal platform?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I could not find in Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls classes a property for a button to make its text move to the next line. For example for a TextBox I can do TextWrapping="Wrap" but what should we do for a button?

Comment: Did you try this? [how to set textwrapping in button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604670/how-to-set-textwrapping-in-button)

Comment: No, it helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<Button Width="50" Height="50">
    <TextBlock Text="Lengthy Data...." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Button>
```